# Is "and" grammatically correct in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, writing

I wrote this sentence:

> I choosed XXX University not just because it is a well-known university in the scientific community **and** its highly valued education, but...

I don't know if *and* is grammatically correct.

Comment: How about: "I chose XXX University not only because of its invaluable education and its reputation in the scientific community, but ..."

Comment: @DamkerngT.I think it sounds good with "...because it is a well-known university...", instead of that "because of" form that you suggested. And also you replaces "just" with "only" - both are possible, a matter of writer's call at the end. Overall I think the original sentence is fine as it is.

Comment: @Man_From_India Though it's a matter of choice, there is one problem with the OP's sentence, which is the part: *because [it is a well-known university in the scientific community] and [its highly valued education]*. Ah, StoneyB just posted what I'm about to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trying to say something like "not only because of A and B, but also Z".

Here is my suggestion (I changed your wording a little, but tried my best to convey the same meaning):

> I chose XXX University not only because of its invaluable education and its reputation in the scientific community, but also ...

Comment: I think you're right about what the OP is trying to say.  So, I'm going to say that your answer is better than mine.  :)  @Marco: you might think of my answer as giving some additional information that might be useful.

Comment: @Marco The first time I posted it, I couldn't come up with a nice adjective in place of "highly valued" (there is nothing wrong with "highly valued education", actually, it's quite common). Now I can think of a few alternatives: "highly regarded education", "highly respected education", and "respectable education".

Answer (score 5):

*And* joins constituents which play the same syntactic role.

The sentence you have written may be reduced to

> I chose XXX University not just because [A and B], but also ...

In that construction, both A and B must be able to serve as complements of *because*. *Because* takes a clause as its complement:

> <sup>ok</sup>because [it is a well known university in the scientific community]

But *because* cannot take an NP as a complement; with an NP you must use *because **of***.

> <sup>∗</sup> because [its highly valued education]
>   <sup>ok</sup>because **of** [its highly valued education]

Consequently, you need to rewrite your sentence so your A and B are syntactically parallel:

> ... because [[it **is** a well known university in the scientific community] and [its education **is** highly valued]]
>   ... because of [ [**its reputation** in the scientific community] and [**its** highly valued **education**]

Answer (score 0):

The sentence isn't correct.  You should use "but" here because of the negation (the "not").  "Not X but Y" or "not just ("only" is also common here) X but also Y" are common constructions in English.  (We use "and" in an "X and Y" construction.)  Also, choose is a "strong" verb; the correct past tense is "chose", not "choosed".  So:

> I chose XXX University not just because it is a well-known university in the scientific community, but also because of its highly-valued education.

I wouldn't add anything to this sentence, so I left your "but..." off of the end.  Now, here's how you could use "and":

> I chose XXX University because it is a well-known university in the scientific community, and [also] because of its highly-valued education.

As you can see, taking the "not" out of the sentence allows you to use an "X and Y" construction.  This is of course also common.

Comment: I think OP intends the reputation and the education to be conjoined under the *not only*, and has omitted as irrelevant the matter which is to follow *but*.

Comment: I think so too. I meant to explain that whatever irrelevant matter he has omitted should be put into a new sentence.

Comment: I mean that I think OP intends "I chose X not only because of A and B but also [because of C]."